# Multiple event sources in a main loop without 100% cpu usage

Tags: c, linux, xlib

I've written a program in C which has a main loop that looks something like this:

```c
   while (running) {

     int recv = read_line(fd1, buf, sizeof(buf));
     if (recv > -1) {
       processCommand(buf);
     }
 
     while (XPending(display)) {
       XNextEvent(display, &ev); // This is blocking
       // Handle event
     }
   }
```

You can see that we have 2 event sources, one of which is blocking.

This works fine but it means I have 100% CPU usage. Normally in a program like this, the blocking call would take care of that but because I have 2 things to check, I can't allow the loop to be blocked.

What's the correct way to program this such that:

- The CPU is not used at 100%
- Both event sources are checked every loop.

Comment: One possibility is to handle the sources with separate threads. That way, you only need simple loops with blocking calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, 'select' or 'poll' are your friends. To get the file descriptor of your display:

ConnectionNumber(display)

```
int XConnectionNumber(Display *display);
```

Both return a connection number for the specified display. On a POSIX-conformant system, this is the file descriptor of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement an event loop with multiple sources in C is using `select` or `poll`.

`select()` allows you waiting to an event on multiple file descriptors or a timeout.

look at the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)

Comment: Yes but both poll() and select() requires a file descriptor to wait on. So, additional stuff is needed to have file descriptors associated to each kind of input events.